# Communicating between UITableView and UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview

Here is what I am trying to achieve..

I have a UITableView and each row is a UITableViewCell. They both are nibs.

Each cell has a button (checkbox) and a label. User can either touch the checkbox to select OR touch the row. In either case, BOTH should happen :

1. If user touches the row, the checkbox gets checked.
2. If user touches the checkbox, the row gets selected.

Achieving 2 is easy, how would I implement 1? i.e. whenever the user touches the row, the checkbox should be automatically be selected.

I added the following code in my UITableViewCell subclass.

```
(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [checkboxButton setSelected:YES];
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks
Amy

Comment: In other words can a UITableViewCell act as a controller as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question but I think did the same thing before - by having the checkbox as an accessory view. There are associated methods for when the user selects the accessory view, and when they are called you can update whatever data they are tied to. Then, do a [tableView reloadData] to update the cells.

As far as the row getting selected, in the documentation - "You should never use selection to indicate state. Instead, use check marks and accessory views for showing state"

Comment: Thanks, my App is similar to the Stocks app - I can select a row by touching the row and once selected can either touch the button which either shows the %age change or the number change. - Amy

Comment: So the button inside of the row would act as a toggle? I think my suggestion fits in that case.